# GUI Python program

Tags: raspbian, python, gui

I have created a Python GUI application and want it to be the only thing shown when Raspberry opens and closes.
Something like a OS on top of Linux.
That is without having a bar on top and with almost no way to close it.
Is this possible and if yes how can I do it ?

Comment: Hello and welcome: The magic word you're looking for is "kiosk mode".

Comment: Have you done a general search?  The question doesn't appear to be particular to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It is particularly cause I want it to be stable for that particular machine with the Rasbian on top.